# Is there a way to pass values using intents from one adapter to another in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-adapter

I have 2 adapters in my class and I am trying to pass values from one adapter to another. I am having a hard time doing it.
This is the code of my first adapter where I am trying to send values from:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final ViewHolder myViewHolder = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
    final Department_model model = models_list.get(i);
    myViewHolder.department_text.setText(model.getDepartment_Name());
    myViewHolder.relative_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Categories.class);
            intent.putExtra("category_name", models_list.get(i).Category_Name);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The second adapter is:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    String name = "";
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringExtra("category_name");


    final ViewHolder myViewHolder = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
    final Department_model model = models_list.get(i);
    myViewHolder.category_textview.setText(name);
}
```

The line `Intent intent = getIntent();` doesn't work so I was wondering if there is a way to do it ?

Comment: Maybe `Shared Preference` will help you.  Have you give that a try ?

Comment: Call back? interface? Event? anything?

Comment: in Categories Activity call your bundle in onStart and get your extra from your bundle and pass it to second adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using second adapter in second activity. If this is the case then you can do below steps

1) As in first adapter you are passing value via intent, this is perfectly alright. But when you are starting the second activity, you need to get values from intent in onCreate method of the second activity. As you are using below code that is perfectly alright.But you need to below code in oncreate method of second activity as mentioned below

```
String name = "";
Intent intent = getIntent();
name = intent.getStringExtra("category_name");
```

Now you have accessed the **category name in the variable "name"**.

2) Now you can pass this variable **name** in the adapter via constructor or via setter method of adapter.

3) Now you have access the value of variable **name** and now you can use it accordingly in your adapter wherever you want.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: no there is no second activity for second adapter, there are two adapters for one class

Comment: but as you mentioned in your code in first adapter on the event of click you are starting second activity. what is purpose of that then? please ellaborate that so you will be given proper guide

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Thank you.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I would like to ask you something more. I need to pass the category name as a list. So I tried using intent.putStringArrayListExtra("category_name",models_list.get(i).Category_Name);. But since my getCategoryName is of the type string, it doesn't work.
Is there a way to pass the categoryName in a list to my activity ?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I just did. Sorry for the delay. Could you please go and have a look? Thanks a lot !

Comment: have you post the question ? if yes please share the link with me

Comment: @AbdulWaheed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551671/how-to-pass-model-type-lists-using-intents-from-the-adapter-to-another-activity

Answer (score 0):

Since you have both the adapters in the same Activity what you can do is get the selected value in activity and before loading the new Adapter you pass the index or value of the in second adapter as a parameter.