# How to pass model type lists using intents from the adapter to another activity

Tags: android-intent, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a Department list that contains the department names, for example, Mens, Ladies, etc. Now if suppose, I click on 'Ladies', the next screen should be displayed with the categories list that are correlated to the Department Ladies .
With my present code, only the first item on the category list is displayed. This is my code for my Department Adapter:

```
public class Department_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
public static Context context;
private ArrayList<Department_model> arraylist;
private List<Department_model> models_list;


public Department_Adapter(Context context, List<Department_model> department_modelList) {
    this.models_list = department_modelList;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Department_model>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(department_modelList);
    this.context = context;
}


public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.departments_childview, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final ViewHolder myViewHolder = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
    final Department_model model = models_list.get(i);
    myViewHolder.department_text.setText(model.getDepartment_Name());
    myViewHolder.relative_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Categories.class);
            String items[] = new String[models_list.size()];
            for(int j=0; j< items.length; j++) {
                intent.putExtra("category_name", models_list.get(i).Category_Name);
                intent.putExtra("category_id", models_list.get(i).Category_ID);
                intent.putExtra("subCatName", models_list.get(i).Sub_Cat_Name);
                intent.putExtra("subcatID", models_list.get(i).Sub_Cat_ID);
                intent.putExtra("Article_ID", models_list.get(i).Article_ID);
                intent.putExtra("Article_Number", models_list.get(i).Article_Number);
                intent.putExtra("ArticleWSP", models_list.get(i).ArticleWSP);

                intent.putExtra("department_name", models_list.get(i).Department_Name);
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models_list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView department_text;
    ImageView right_arrow;
    RelativeLayout relative_lay;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        department_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.department_text);
        right_arrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_arrow);
        relative_lay = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_lay);
    }
}
```

}

This is my Category class:

```
public class Categories extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView category_recyclerView;
TextView category_textview;
ImageView back_arrow;
static Context ctx;
private static List<Category_model> category_modelList;
private static List<String> list;
private Category_Adapter category_adapter;
String cat_name, cat_id, title, subCatName, subcatID, Article_ID, Article_Number, ArticleWSP;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ctx = Categories.this;


        Intent intent = getIntent();
    cat_name = intent.getStringExtra("category_name");
    cat_id = intent.getStringExtra("category_id");
    subCatName = intent.getStringExtra("subCatName");
    subcatID = intent.getStringExtra("subcatID");
    Article_ID = intent.getStringExtra("Article_ID");
    Article_Number = intent.getStringExtra("Article_Number");
    ArticleWSP = intent.getStringExtra("ArticleWSP");

        title = intent.getStringExtra("department_name");


    category_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_recyclerView);
    category_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category_textview);
    back_arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
    category_textview.setText(title);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    category_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    category_recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    category_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(Categories.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    category_modelList = new ArrayList<>();





        Category_model obj1 = new Category_model();
        obj1.setCategory_Name(cat_name);
        obj1.setCategory_ID(cat_id);
        category_modelList.add(obj1);



        category_adapter = new Category_Adapter(Categories.this, category_modelList);
        category_recyclerView.setAdapter(category_adapter);



    back_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

}

How can I pass all the Category list items when clicked on the particular position of the Department list ?

Comment: It is happening because there is a logical problem in your code.

Comment: I know that. Could you please guide me as to what the code should be ? I am new to Android, hence struggling. Thank you ! @AbdulWaheed

Comment: please see my answer and let me know if this is something helpful.

Comment: and feel free to ask if you have any problem or question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see logical problem in your code. This is the part of the code creating problem.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Categories.class);
        String items[] = new String[models_list.size()];
        for(int j=0; j< items.length; j++) {
            intent.putExtra("category_name", models_list.get(i).Category_Name);
            intent.putExtra("category_id", models_list.get(i).Category_ID);
            intent.putExtra("subCatName", models_list.get(i).Sub_Cat_Name);
            intent.putExtra("subcatID", models_list.get(i).Sub_Cat_ID);
            intent.putExtra("Article_ID", models_list.get(i).Article_ID);
            intent.putExtra("Article_Number", models_list.get(i).Article_Number);
            intent.putExtra("ArticleWSP", models_list.get(i).ArticleWSP);

            intent.putExtra("department_name", models_list.get(i).Department_Name);
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Here you are initializing **items string array with size of model_list **.This does not make sense. Your arrray size should be of the size of **Available Category** And here definitely no one knows how long will be the last with **category** The long the **model_list It may have any number of matching category**. So, simple array is not a good idea. You need to use ArrayList. ArrayList of custom mode. Here Custom Model will be   your category mode.Like mentioned below

```
List<CategoryModel> categoryList = new ArrayList();
```

And on the even of click, you need to get position as to what position item is clicked. And then you need to get **model object** of that position. And after getting model you need to find actual Category. And with category you need to select **one property like 'name or id ' of that category** . Now this will be your filter point. Now filter your **model_list** (if this is list that contains your category as well. As I can see it is Department List. If this department list also contain category then you need to use list to filter the list). To filter you need to use below code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Categories.class);
    List<CategoryModel> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    //you need to get position of clicked item and that is stored in variable 'i'
    Department_model selectedModel = model_list.get(i);
    //here you have option you can filter with or the id let's suppose you are filtering with name then
    // get name of category
    String filterTag = selectedModel.Category_Name;
    for(int j=0; j< model_list.size(); j++) {
        //you need make category model with getter and setter properties
        if (filterTag.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedModel.Category_Name)) {
            CategoryModel  currentCategory = new CategoryModel();
            currentCategory.set(Category_Name);
            currentCategory.set(Category_ID);
            currentCategory.set(Sub_Cat_Name);
            currentCategory.set(Sub_Cat_ID);
            currentCategory.set(Article_ID);
            currentCategory.set(Article_Number);
            currentCategory.set(ArticleWSP);
            currentCategory.set(Department_Name);

            //here you have mapped category stuff in category model now you need to add in the list
            categoryList.add(currentCategory);
        }

    }

    Log.e("list_size",categoryList.size() );

    //after loop, you need to pass "categoryList" to the next activity and then use the same categoryList
    //to new activity of category adapter and now you are done ... phewww
    //you can use below code to pass list via intent 
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)categoryList);
    intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

In **Category Activity onCreate() method** use below code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
List<CategoryModel> list = args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

And now are done do whatever you want to do with this list.

**update** after finishing loop, I am checking list size. you need to check the size and please let me know

Comment: Thanks for the good compliment first. as far as matter of passing list fromadapter to the activity is concerned if you check last lines of the code that does the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. I tried implementing your code, but I am getting only the first value of the category list. I think I am doing something wrong while setting the category model. This is what I have done, please could you tell me if its wrong ? I think since I am using the 'ith' position, that is why its coming the same first value.
'currentCategory.setCategory_Name(models_list.get(i).Category_Name);'
Thanks a ton !

Comment: may be you have only one item in the list with that category. First you need to check in model list how many time you are inside the loop. if that is more than one this means you have more than one values if not that means you have only noe value...if you have more values then let me know. Will try to solve your problem

Comment: I just checked, the loop is iterating multiple times but only the first item on the list is getting added. It isn't moving to the next item in the category list. I have modified my code a little, currentCategory.setCategory_Name(model.Category_Name);" instead of  'currentCategory.setCategory_Name(models_list.get(i).Category_Name)'

Comment: Also one more thing, where are we using the filterTag ? We have so far only defined it, haven't used it anywhere

Comment: ohhh my bad... you are right... I am updating the code accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much ! You have no idea how you have saved my life !

Comment: why are you using variable 'i' you need to use that variable which is being used in for-loop. because that will be updated variable and will be iterating over list with different items.. hope this will help you.

Comment: Oh my bad, I changed it to j, the variable in the for loop, but it is now displaying all the items in the category in each department. Instead of showing only those items that are correlated to their separate departments. Is it because of not using filterTag ? Last help please and sorry to bother you this much

Comment: :) yes it is happening due to not using filter tag... and i have updated my code in for loop please have a look...if you have any problem feel free to ask

Comment: I updated the for loop, but I am getting the same output. All the categories are being displayed under all the departments. I do not understand what's the problem ?

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you but I think there is some problem with the filterTag. it is adding all the category items into a single department. Could you please help me how to get only distinguished items ?

Comment: then you need to debug things in details what are the value actullay available and what you are filtering.